# Germany inter state traveling

Tags: germany, covid-19

I need to travel to Dresden from India and there is no direct flight. So I will be traveling to Frankfurt airport and will catch a train to Dresden. Is it possible to travel to Dresden and take quarantine?

Comment: I suggest you read my [answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/158456/104980) to a question from last July. While details might have changed (you need to announce your arrival via a [website](https://www.einreiseanmeldung.de/#/) to the officials), the basics "you may transit to your final destination and quarantine there" haven't changed.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.